# Подгружать изображения с других сайтов через свой URL

Tags: php

Такой вопрос. У меня на сайте используются изображения с разных сайтов.
Вот пример кода как сейчас это у меня:

```
<img src="ссылка на картинку с другого сайта">
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать что то в таком духе:

```
<img src="https://mysite.com/load_photo.php?url=тут ссылка на изображение на другом сайте">
```

**Через некоторые время нашел такой способ.** Но если передавать ссылку через GET не работает, если указывать в самом коде то работает. Что не так.

```
<img src="load_img.php?u=http://cdn.bfm.ru/news/maindocumentphoto/2016/03/04/schkvf.jpg'" alt="">
```

А вот сам файл load_img.php

```
if( isset($_GET["u"]) ){

header('Content-type: image/png');
$url = urlencode($_GET["u"]);
echo $str;

}
```

Если в самом файле вместо `$url = urlencode($_GET["u"]);` сделать так то все норм `$url = 'http://cdn.bfm.ru/news/maindocumentphoto/2016/03/04/schkvf.jpg';`

Почему не работает если через GET передаю ссылку?

Comment: ключевой вопрос - зачем

Comment: @teran есть картинки с сайтов которые заблокированы моим интернет провайдером, хочу таким образом обойти эти блокировки.

Comment: самый простой способ тут будет при первом обращении сохранить картинку к себе, а потом уже делать на нее редиректы. (Вернее самый-то простой - это скачивать и отдавать каждый раз, но это плохо). Но лучше как-то заменять ссылку при этом. Тут уже все зависит от того где и как эта разметка у вас хранится.

Comment: @teran там много картинок, качать их всех на сервер не вариант.

Comment: проксировать через себя все картинки тоже так себе идея. альтернативный враинат - вешайте на картинки `onerror` если у юзера заблокировано, то проксируйте, ну или по предложенной схеме сохраняйте только ошибочные, посмотрите как будет объем расти.

Answer (score 0):

У вас ошибка в ссылке `...schkvf.jpg'"` лишняя кавычка в конце. Влюбом случае рекомендую кодировать параметры URL так:

```
<?
$imgUrl = 'http://cdn.bfm.ru/news/maindocumentphoto/2016/03/04/schkvf.jpg';
?>
<img src="load_img.php?u=<?= urlencode($imgUrl) ?>" alt="">
```

или лучше так, особенно если параметров несколько:

```
<img src="load_img.php?<?= http_build_query([
    'u' => 'http://cdn.bfm.ru/news/maindocumentphoto/2016/03/04/schkvf.jpg'
]) ?>" alt="">
```

В файле load_img.php наверно должно быть что-то типа

```
<?php
if($imgUrl = filter_input(INPUT_GET,'u',FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)){
    header('Content-type: image/jpg'); // тут нужна логика по определению типа картинки
    echo file_get_contents($imgUrl);
}
```